# Display the users reviews in a tableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-places-api, swift4

I'm trying to adding in a tableView the users reviews taken from google places API

```
"reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "Robert Ardill",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106422854611155436041/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T47KxWuAoJU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZo/BDmyI12BZAs/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba1/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
            "text" : "Awesome offices. Great facilities, location and views. Staff are great hosts",
            "time" : 1491144016
         }
      ],
```

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details, for now i'm trying to add only the rating, author_name and text, this is my custom tableViewCell

```
import UIKit




class myReviewTableCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var revText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var revRating: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var revAuthor: UILabel!

     var place: EClass?




    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }




    func revSelect(place:Eclass) {



        NearbyPlaces.getPlaceDetails(place: place) { (place) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let rev = place.details?["reviews"] as? [String:Any] {




                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where i need to build properly the `func revSelect(place:Eclass)` and after call it in my cellForRowAt. I already tried to add other parameters like

```
if (place.details?["website"] as? String) != nil {
                self.webButton.isHidden = false
                  }
               else {
                self.webButton.isHidden = true
            }


            if let phoneNumber = place.details?["international_phone_number"] as? String {
                self.myLabel4.text = "\(phoneNumber)"
            }
            else {
                self.myLabel4.isHidden = true
              }
         }
      }
```

and they work well, but reviews is an array so is different, i also tried to follow the logic of the parameters "geometry"

```
if let g = placeInfo["geometry"] as? [String:Any] {
            if let l = g["location"] as? [String:Double] {
                if let lat = l["lat"], let lng = l["lng"] {
                    location = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
                }
            }
        }
```

that i added in another class, but it did not work. So what i have to do in my func revSelect to make rev.Author.text = "author_name" , revText = "text" etc. ?? (I already asked before about this but i could not solve the problem)

//UPDATE

this is the func that i use to get place details

```
static func getPlaceDetails(place:EClass, completion: @escaping (EClass) -> Void) {

        guard place.details == nil else {
            completion(place)
            return
        }

        var params : [String : Any]
        params = [
            "key" : AppDelegate.googlePlacesAPIKey,
            "placeid" : place.placeId,
        ]

        Alamofire.request(googlePlaceDetailsHost, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)).responseJSON { response in
            let value = response.result.value as? [String : Any]
            place.details = (value)?["result"] as? [String : Any]
          /*  print(((value)?["result"] as? [String : Any] ?? [String : Any]()).debugDescription) */
            completion(place)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to research JSON parsing in Swift. This [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) would be a good read.

JSON is quite easy to read once you understand how it is structured. You just need to map each type properly. Swift 4 Introduced the Codable protocol which when combined with JSONDecoder give you a much better way of parsing and using this data.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var reviews: [Review]
}

struct Review: Codable {

    var authorName: String
    var authorUrl: String
    var rating: Int
    var text: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case authorName = "author_name"
        case authorUrl = "author_url"
        case rating
        case text
    }
}

let data = """
{
    "reviews" : [{
        "author_name" : "Robert Ardill",
        "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106422854611155436041/reviews",
        "language" : "en",
        "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T47KxWuAoJU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZo/BDmyI12BZAs/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba1/photo.jpg",
        "rating" : 5,
        "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
        "text" : "Awesome offices. Great facilities, location and views. Staff are great hosts",
        "time" : 1491144016
    }]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)

guard let data = data else { throw NSError() }

let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
let reviews = response?.reviews // array of reviews
let review = reviews?.first // first one from the list (if any)

print(review?.authorName)
print(review?.rating)
```

So using the example above, I have created a Review type and mapped the properties of this type to the types in the JSON response. Then we can use JSONDecoder to do the rest of the work for us.

> **OUTPUT**:
>
> Optional("Robert Ardill")
>
> Optional(5)

**UPDATE:**

You need to do something like this, but you may need to change the structs structure based on the response values.

```
Alamofire.request(googlePlaceDetailsHost, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)).responseJSON { response in
    guard let data = response.data else { throw NSError() }

    let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    let reviews = response?.reviews // array of reviews
    completion(reviews?.first)
}
```

Comment: ok i gave a look at this, a question, doing this i get the right result of the given place? Because i have tried but the response that gives me is that of the example that there is, so for example the author name rather than give me the real author name of the review, gives me by Robert Ardill that would be that of the example

Comment: See where I have `let data = """` and the JSON text? Ignore that part. that is just my test JSON to give example. You use the JSON returned from the API. I'll update the answer in a few mins

Comment: I have updated with example how to get the `data` from the Alamofire response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [object mapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) and there is documentation on github